# Google Firebase URL Shortener in C#

Tags: c#, api, firebase, url

I've been using the Google URL shortener for years, now I just receive a notification that the API will retire. I was not actively managing my code but now I need to :(

Anyway, I have no clue how to change my code. I managed to get a new Google Firebase API key, but now?

This is the guidance Google gives ... https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest ... right. Not much there, no coding examples ... I am not really a coder, so I am stuck already.

This is my original code:

```
     string shorturl;
     string GoogleAPIkey = "mylittlesecret";
     var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=" + GoogleAPIkey);
     httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
     httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
     string longurl = "http://www.google.com";

     using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))

            {
                string json = "{\"longUrl\":\"" + longurl + "\"}";
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }


    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))

            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseText);
                shorturl = data.id;
            }


    Console.WriteLine("This is the short URL:" + shorturl);
```

Any guidance on how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation link you provide, the only difference seems to be the URL of request and the parameter name.

---

Instead of https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key= + yourApiKey

Use https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key= + yourFirebaseApiKey

---

And, instead of `string json = "{\"longUrl\":\"" + longurl + "\"}";`

you could use: `string json = "{\"longDynamicLink\":\"" + longurl + "\"}";`

---

**EDIT:** Giving it a second look, i just noticed your long url is missing something very important, your firebase domain. e.g. "https://zbr8b.app.goo.gl/?link="

In order for the url shortener service to work, we must provide both our api key and the domain related to it that we got for use in dynamic links, so in this case we're just missing the domain:

```
//You can find this in your firebase console in "Dynamic Links"
string myFBDomain= "https://zbr8b.app.goo.gl/?link="; 
string longUrl = myFBDomain + "https://google.com?id=123";
```

Note that it is also important to use the correct schema of our url of interest, either *http* or *https*.

Comment: My only changes: `string post = "{\"longDynamicLink\":\"" + url + "\"}";
            
            var url_REST_API = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url_REST_API + _key));`

Comment: @user9467387 not yet

Comment: Pity. Keep us posted if you find a solution.

Comment: Anyone figured this out? I am also stuck. I also get **400 BadRequest**

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with this: (NOTE: you had data.id, had to change to data.shortlink)

```
string GoogleAPIkey = "YOUR FB PROJECT API";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=" + GoogleAPIkey);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    string longurl = "https://YOURDOMAIN.page.link/?link=https://www.YOURLONGURL.com/account?g=sdasdhaskjdh4547576aksgskjg";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))

    {
        string json = "{\"longDynamicLink\":\"" + longurl + "\"}";
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }


    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))

    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseText);
        shorturl = data.shortLink;
    }



    Response.Write(shorturl);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a try one day! Thanks for commenting!